# Why page is scrolling up while dinamic content is changing?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I trying to make website with 4 blocks:

1. block with `height: 100vh`
2. block with `height: 100vh`
3. block with `fit-content height` (long block, more than 100vh)
4. block with some content

All these blocks are in the container with next properties:

`scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;`

`overflow-y: scroll;`

`height: 100vh;`

1,2,3 blocks has next properties:

`height: 100vh;`
`scroll-snap-align: start;`

All these properties needed for me to create full-page scroll event (if user will scroll a bit -> full page will be scrolled to next block).

It working well, but I have a dinamic content from server in my 3 block, so If my content is changing last page scrolled up to start.

How to repair it?

P.S. example. https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-almeida-0dkg45?file=/src/App.js try to scroll to very down and press the button